# Is there a way to create a invite to only be used by a specific user? - Disnake

Tags: python, discord

About: I am using Disnake in python (version 3.9.7)

Hello all,

I am trying to make a bot where bot a creates a server (since bots can only be in 10 guilds if you want to be able to create guilds), and then a discord user(me) then invites a main bot which has permission to make slash commands and contains all the moderation code.

I need to create a invite that can only be used by the user that run the command to the main server which the slash command is run in. I am currently using Disnake's disnake.ext.commands.bot rather than disnake.client